# Getting a 500 internal server error for wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress

I already tried doing  memory=128MB solution but it did not work. site and  wp-admin both given same error.

I'm not really sure what else to try. Help?

Comment: Start reading error logs.

Comment: Also changed .htaccess file...no change

Comment: No messages in error log

Comment: I deactivated all plugins from DB...then it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I do when encounter this kind of problems.

1.Turn WP_DEBUG as true in your wp-config.php
2.Using default theme to see if the site is ok or not.
3.Deactivate all plugin to see if the site is ok or not.
4.Activate the plugins one by one to see if the site is ok or not.

Most of time, you can find which theme or plugin break your site when you go through this process.

Comment: Some hosting may disable the error log for security reason. Ask your hosting for more support.